# Unity 2D Trigger should only get triggered by one Player Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game with one player as a prefab. And I have an apple with a 2D Trigger on it. But I only want that the trigger only gets triggered by the Player Prefab and not by the moving platforms.
But if i do this:
  `if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {`
or this:
  `if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {`

My Trigger doesn't recognize the Player.
What should I do?

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NeuerTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Geht");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your player object is not tagged `Player` correctly ... Btw you could also create a layer for the player and in the physics 2D settings adjust the collision layer matrix so only this exact layer can even collide with the trigger

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not understanding how **trigger** is working.

Make sure that

**1** On your apple there is a rigidbody and a collider with **isTrigger** to true

**2** On your player there is a collider and a rigidbody

**3** ON your player you have the tag "Player" in the inspector

If this is all like this then if you put this on the apple script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.compareTag("Player")
// player touches apple
}
```

Comment: @Rezureax it will enter the trigger if it touches the platform, but it will enter the if only with the player, unless you have a tag Player in your platform xD

Comment: top! :D @Rezureax

Comment: @Rezureax if it is working check the answer as correct for question purpose